# Fleas persist on cat days after treatment

Tags: cats, fleas

My two tabby cats have had fleas since we got them as kittens over a year ago.

We're using Advocate as prescribed by the vet, once a month and have done for nearly a year now.

I've treated the house with Virbac spray a couple of times now.

But fleas are persisting!

My main worries are that either we don't apply the treatment perfectly, and too much goes on the fur. Or that I don't treat the house well enough and there are still eggs here and there. Both very possible.

This month though, we were so careful and applied the treatment *really* well to one of the cats at least. Three days later, I've combed her with the flea comb and removed 26 fleas (I counted!), and that was until she'd had enough - I hadn't even started on her tummy where most of the fleas like to hang out. I assume I would have got over 50 if she'd let me. They did vary in size, but most were fully grown fleas.

So question is, is that normal? It seems to me like Advocate just isn't doing the job. Surely she couldn't have 50 *new* fleas in 3 days? Surely this means that the treatment hasn't worked and all those fleas have lived through it.

If we're confident that we applied the treatment well then where do we go from here?

Any advice / experience will be greatly appreciated.

-- two  tabby cats, one small female, one medium sized male, both neutered / spayed, not house cats, small female always seems to have them worst --

Comment: Did you ask your vet again during the one year of treatment? What did they say?

Comment: You mention "not house cat" in the last paragraph. Does that mean they (or at least one of them) can go outside? If yes, they might bring new fleas back from outside every time. You need to treat them for the current flea infestation *and* with a prophylactic flea repellant.

Comment: @Allerleirauh the vet thinks that we must not apply the treatment properly, or haven't treated the house enough. This time though, I feel we did do the treatment well, so that's why I posted.

Comment: Thanks @Elmy yes, they both go outside. I didn't know about the repellent. I will look that up. However, I don't think that she could have got all those fully grown fleas after 3 days of going outside. Do you agree?

Comment: Of course she would. Some types of fleas live in lose, dry sand, for example. Your cat may dig in this sand and the fleas jump on her. They then lay their eggs in the fur.

Comment: Depending on the neighborhood, how many and what type of other animals are around, there could be a huge population of adult fleas. You may need to find where your cats go and do some cleanup there. But be sensitive to neighbor property and don't do things without permission.